# Insert result to table of updating column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have this situation I'm doing a update statement on sql script in postgres, when I found matching record I want to update content and also save to other table for example id_user for who's I did update is it possible with use plpgsql.
Can you give me any tips what terms I will should search on google ?

ex.

```
update User set Status "Active" where any_condition when success insert to UserHistoryTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a normal update with a `RETURNING *` inside a CTE, and from there insert the data in the history table:

```
WITH j AS (
 UPDATE tbuser SET status = 'Active' 
 WHERE id = 42 
 RETURNING *)
INSERT INTO user_hist SELECT * FROM j;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=42a90594168c220e6cb56fe93929ab83)

If you want to save the value before the update I suggest you take a look at `triggers`.